# Capture spellchecked words from browser input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, spell-checking

In HTML, when [the spellcheck global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck) is enabled for an input (`spellcheck="true"`), most browsers display misspelled words with a dotted red underline.

Is there a way to use JavaScript (or anything else) to record which words the browser has marked as misspelled?

Developers can duplicate what the browser is doing by implementing their own spellchecks, but is there any approach to simply piggyback off of the work the client's browser is doing already?

I'd love to end up with something like an array `misspells = ['hapy', 'delerious', 'tipical']`, or ideally a way to replace the browser's locally displayed mark with a tag of some sort in the saved text which I could later parse.

Comment: I know that deals with Chrome specifically, but if it's not doable in chrome, it's not doable :)